# What happens to a SQS message if listener gets killed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Say, I have one SQS and a listener process listening to that queue. Say, there is one message, and while processing the message, say the process got killed automatically. Then, what will happen to this message? Will it again go to SQS or remain in flight? Or will it go to DLQ, if configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your measages will have an “invisibility time-out”. During that time window they won’t be returned by subsequent request for messages.

Once the timeout expires, the message will be returned by another call.

Once you “ack” the message it won’t be processed again.

Generally SQS uses “at least once” semantics. Up to the maximum age of your queue it will reprocess messages until they are successfuly processed.

Absent something really crazy (where you keep failing the message for 14 days), it will ensure that your message is processed.

It does mean the code you run in response to a message needs to be idempotent (needs to run more than once with out changing the result).

But if you can do that, and you can respond to bugs in your code faster than 14 days, then you will be guranteed to have your message processed.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Few doubts in the answer: 1. What do you mean by invisibility time-out? Where can I see how much time it would be? 2. What do you mean by "Once the timeout expires, the message will be returned by another call."? Does it mean the message would again come in SQS? 3. What do you mean by ack? Does it mean, if the message is received by the listener once, it won't be processed again even the listener got killed?

Comment: The queue has a “default invisibility timeout” you can set in the queue properties. That can be overrides by a call to “ChangeMessageVisibility”.  To “ack” a message you can call  “DeleteMessage”. Sorry if this was “too much inside baseball”, but “ack” in a “distributed systr

Comment: The queue has a “default invisibility timeout” you can set in the queue properties. That can be overrides by a call to “ChangeMessageVisibility”.  To “ack” a message you can call  “DeleteMessage”. Sorry if this was “too much inside baseball”, but “ack” in a “distributed systems” context means to “acknowledge a message”, or to “indicate that it doesn’t need to be processed anymore” because it’s been handled. If you are super worried about implementing this properly, I highly recommend using AWS Lambda and its “async invoke” features. It will just “do the right thing”.